# Azure API Management optional caching

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

The main problem is that I would like to do optional caching with Azure APIM. The main reason for using cache is to improve performance. Also, still would like to control the cache option and also duration by using headers. By default there's no cache. The cache should be optional to customers.

I've tried using `cache-lookup-value` as it enables you to cache by a key, also there's a plan to use a token value to fulfill the optional cache feature. But I came across the performance degradation with usage of above mentioned `cache-lookup-value`.

Is there maybe another way/workaround option how to do it better ? Maybe also with Redis ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, as you said to enable optional caching with Azure APIM, you can use the cache-lookup policy. It allows you to cache responses based on specified headers or query parameters.
- IF you want to store responses You can also use the [cache-store policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/cache-store-policy) to store responses in the cache.
- If you are facing performance degradation with the cache-lookup-value policy, then you can go with external cache such as Redis. This will allow you to offload the caching workload from APIM and improve performance.
  The MS Document for [Use an external Redis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-cache-external) provides below details.

> Using an external cache enables you to get around some of the built-in
> cache's restrictions:
>
> - Avoid periodic cache clearing during API Management upgrades.
> - additional flexibility in cache configuration
> - Cache more information than the API Management layer permits.

- By following the above document created Azure Cache for Redis and in this by using [Schedule updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-administration#schedule-updates) you can control the days and times of week as shown in below image.
  Go to Created Azure Cache for Redis >> Settings >> Schedule updates.

[image]

- You can also create external cache in your APIM as shown,
  Go to Created API Management service >> External cache >> + Add.
  [image]
  You can also refer these [Custom caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-cache-by-key) for duration related information and   MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/756817/azure-api-management-internal-cache) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm already using the external Redis Cache